# BS4 carousel indicator highlights wrong image on click (active)

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I'm making a BS4 carousel.
I'm using Jquery to fetch images to display. 
The images is named `1.jpg - 72.jpg`
Everything works fine except the indicator thumbnails highlights wrong image on click.

If image 2 is clicked image 3 is highlighted etc.

I can't find out why this is happening.

[here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dadihall/rpy8sh5o/)

I use this `Jquery` to fetch the images and append them to a div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  for(var j = 1; j < 72; j++) {
$('<div class="carousel-item"><img src=" ./images/'+ j+'.jpg " width="100%">   
  </div>').appendTo('.carousel-inner');
$('<li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="'+j+'"><img  src=" ./images/'+ j+'.jpg " class="img- fluid"></li>').appendTo('.carousel-indicators')
console.log(j);
}
$('.carousel-item').first().addClass('active');
$('.carousel-indicators > li').first().addClass('active');
$('#carousel').carousel({
 pause: true,
 interval: true,
});
});
```

The HTML is just basic.

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">            
  <div class='carousel-outer'>
    <div class="carousel-inner"></div>      
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev"> <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" data-slide="next"> <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
      </a>
     </div>
<!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators"></ol>
</div>
```

The css

```
#carousel {
      margin: 20px auto;
      max-height:658px;
      width: 1024px;
  }
  #carousel .carousel-indicators {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
       justify-content: center; 
       padding: 0 15px; 
       width: 100%; 
       position: static; 
       right: 0; 
       bottom: 0; 
       margin-right: 0; 
       margin-left: 0; 

  }
  #carousel .carousel-indicators li {
      background-color: transparent;
      -webkit-border-radius: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
      display: inline-block;
      height: auto;
      margin: 0 !important;
      width: auto;
  }
  #carousel .carousel-indicators li img {
      width: 50px;
      display: block;
      opacity: 0.9;
  }
  #carousel .carousel-indicators li.active img {
      opacity: 1;
  }
  #carousel .carousel-indicators li:hover img {
      opacity: 0.75;
  }
  #carousel .carousel-outer {
      position: relative;
  }

  .carousel-item-next, .carousel-item-prev, .carousel-item.active {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably it happens because of the loop starting from 1 instead of 0.

A possible fix would be to change the `data-slide-to` attribute's value to `j - 1` instead of `j`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  for(var j = 1; j < 72; j++) {
    $('<div class="carousel-item"><img src=" ./images/'+ j +'.jpg " width="100%"></div>').appendTo('.carousel-inner');
    $('<li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="'+ (j - 1) +'"><img  src=" ./images/'+ j +'.jpg " class="img- fluid"></li>').appendTo('.carousel-indicators')
console.log(j);
}
    $('.carousel-item').first().addClass('active');
    $('.carousel-indicators > li').first().addClass('active');
    $('#carousel').carousel({
        pause: true,
        interval: true,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with for loop it starts from 1 and for data-slide-to it must start with 0 , so you can try this

```js
$('<li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="'+(j-1)+'"><img  src=" ./images/'+ j+'.jpg " class="img- fluid"></li>').appendTo('.carousel-indicators')
```

Answer (score 0):

change the `data-slide-to="'+j+'"` to`data-slide-to="'+ (j - 1) +'"`